# User defined macro in CnPack

Tags: delphi, delphi-ide

Do you know how to create an user defined macro in CnPack ?

The instructions shipped with it say it can be done but don't explain how. I tried to sign in the dedicated forum, twice, but it didn't work.

I searched for some tutorials online but didn't find anything either.

Comment: What specific part of the *instructions* are you referring to? Are you talking about the ones in the *Source Templates Wizard* help topic, which says *You can use pre-defined macro or user defined macro in code template*?

Comment: Yes, exactly that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply define the new macro. Here's an example of doing so.

- Open the *Source Templates Options* dialog (*CnPack->Source Templates->Options* from the IDE main menu).
- Select the *Add* button.
- Fill in the information at the top (Title and Description for now), for instance "TestTemplate" and "Test template with my macro". The hard part is finding an unused ShortCut, so let's not bother now.
- In the content area, put in the text you want to insert into your source. Let's try a third type of comment block with some silly information and a macro named *MyMacro* - note that I've surrounded it with `%` characters:

  ```
  (*
     This is a nonsense comment by %MyMacro%
  *)
  ```
- Save the template, and then close the dialog.
- Go into the IDE's Code Editor at the point you want to insert the template. Open the *CnPack->Source Template* menu, where you'll see your new *TestTemplate* at the bottom. Click it, and you'll see a dialog appear:

[image: TestTemplate macro replace dialog]

- Fill in the *Value* (I'll use "Some Value") and click *Ok*. You should see this in the Code Editor:

  ```
  (*
    This is a nonsense comment by Some Value
  *)
  ```